# SELECT YII2 WHERE IN

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Подскажите почему выборка срабатывает и показывает только одну запись

```
$select_account_id = 78,79,119
 $tokens = FbToken::find()->select('id')->where(['in','id', [$select_account_id]])->andWhere(['status' => 1])->andWhere(['hidden' => 0])->all();
```

так только выводит

```
 Array(
  [0] => frontend\models\FbToken Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 78
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 78
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

       )
 )
```

но если сделать так

```
     $tokens = FbToken::find()->select('id')->where(['in','id', [78,79,119]])->andWhere(['status' => 1])->andWhere(['hidden' => 0])->all();
```

получаю

```
Array(
 [0] => frontend\models\FbToken Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 78
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 78
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[1] => frontend\models\FbToken Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 79
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 79
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )

[2] => frontend\models\FbToken Object
    (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 119
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [id] => 119
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_relationsDependencies:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_eventWildcards:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

)

Подскажите что не правильно делаю ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучшим вариантом для IN в Yii2 будет передача массива.

```
$select_account_id = [78,79,80];
$tokens = FbToken::find()->select('id')->where(['in','id', $select_account_id])->andWhere(['status' => 1])->andWhere(['hidden' => 0])->all();
```

Не уверен, упростили ли вы массив, написав `$select_account_id = 78,79,119`, так как это тут неправильный синтаксис и по хорошему оно должно выдать ошибку.
Но даже если не выдаст ошибку, в вашем варианте Вы передаете $select_account_id как единый параметр.

То есть у вас формируется вот такая конструкция: `->where(['in','id', [[78,79,119]])` <- двойные скобки.

Это приведет к тому, что ваш запрос неправильно будет сформирован, так как ожидается одномерный массив, а получается двумерный (еще одна вложенность).

Если же вы и имели ввиду такой синтаксис, тогда скорее всего у вас выключены Warning, и $select_account_id = 78, а все остальное игнорируется.

В результате у вас просто формируется вот такая конструкция: `->where(['in','id', [78])` и вы получаете одну строку.

Comment: Спасибо, не правильно передоверял данные, нужно было массивом, а я строкой их передавал.

Comment: @Sender1050 рад, что разобрались. Если этот ответ подходит, отметьте пожалуйста вопрос выполненным.